# Regex matching specific url but excluding string

Tags: regex, google-analytics

Trying to create a regex for a Google Analytics Goal where the destination is the url below including any parameter eg.

```
/pages/payment/complete.aspx

/pages/payment/complete.aspx?appealtitle=donate-now&paymentid=8276f75a-7f0e

/pages/payment/complete.aspx?paymentid=901f-be2cdb4319a5
```

But not if 'error' appears anywhere in the parameter eg.

```
/pages/payment/complete.aspx?error=12

/pages/payment/complete.aspx?paymentid=f7f19bba-ff1e-48b5-901f-be2cdb4319a5&error=3
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you have so far, and what are the specific problems you're facing with it?

Comment: Negative lookaheads are not supported with GA regex, which I believe is version R2 (or something like that).

Comment: @Welbog With my limited understanding I'm come up with  
    \/pages\/payment\/complete\.aspx\??((?!error).)*$

Comment: @nyuen Does that mean it's not possible?

Comment: Yes, it's not possible to use lookaheads.

Answer (score 1):

This REGEX matches *error* word if it be as a parameter:

```
[?|&]error=\d+
```

Here is an implementation using PHP:

```
$url = '/pages/payment/complete.aspx?error=12';
$pattern = '[?|&]error=\d+';
if ( preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches) ) {
    echo 'This URL is containing some errors';
} else {
    echo 'All fine';
}
```

#### [Demo](https://3v4l.org/YBvNJ)

Comment: How would I use this in Google Analytics?

Comment: How do you access those URLs?

Comment: I need to drop the regex string into the box for the Google Analytics goal destination

Comment: Do you mean you need to extract something of that URL? if yes, do you need which part of URL exactly?

Comment: No, it's to track a goal in Google Analytics

Answer (score 0):

In Google Analytics it's not possible to use lookaheads, therefore the above can't be achieved.